# jQuery AJAX is not showing output after first PHP conditional

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-tools

I am having trouble using the jQuery AJAX call. The query runs properly and debug output also shows the correct data, but anything apart from the first PHP conditional in the document being called is not being shown.

First, there are two buttons, one linked to "core" the other "email":

Here's the relevant JavaScript:

```
$("#core").click(function(){
    loaddetails ("core");
});
$("#email").click(function(){
    loaddetails ("email");
});

function loaddetails(type) { var query = "details=" + type; 
    $.post("details.php", query , function( data ) {
     $("#d-features").html(data); alert (data);});
    return false;
};
```

And the contents of details.php:

```
<? if($_POST['details']=='core'){ ?> blah1 <? }
   if($_POST['details']=='email') { ?> blah2 <? } ?>
```

Both "blah1" and "blah2" appear in the alert box debug output. But, only "blah1" ever gets posted on the page div (#d-features), as "blah2" never appears on the page.

I have checked Firebug and there are absolutely no errors. But I suspect the second conditional request may have gone in a loop, as the alert window showing up when "email" button is clicked shows "Prevent page from creating additional dialogs", though no additional dialogs show up even when unchecked.

What is causing this problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure `loaddetails("email");` is being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems to be a conflict with the tabs effect I loaded for a div that encompassed these links. So once I removed that effect, it works now. But I'm not sure what is wrong with the effect yet, I'll post another question to figure it out.

Thanks to those that offered assistance!

Answer (score 0):

.html() replaces the content instead of appending.

Try changing that line to see if all the data is returned from both calls:

`$("#d-features").html(data);` ==> `$("#d-features").append(data);`

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried that and unfortunately it still does not work. It shows "blah1" and "blah2" only when the first button ('core') is clicked. Then it repeats with its own blah1. 

I want to replace the content on the second call anyway with the "blah2", so I think html is what I want. Append only duplicates the info, and for some reason does not display the results of the second button even though it grabbed it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A small modification on your code, you could try to see if this works:

```
function loaddetails(type) { 
    $.post(
        "details.php", 
        {
            details:    type
        }, 
        function( data ) {
            $("#d-features").html(data); 
             alert (data);
        }
    );
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I added the missing } after "type" to your code, and unfortunately it still does not work! Only "blah1" shows, no "blah2". But Firebug shows the correct text retrieved via ajax, i.e. "blah2". It's just not getting posted on the page for some odd reason. I'm pulling my hair out.

Comment: Weird.. I edited my post to add the missing }, thanks for noticing. Does "Blah2" alerts or not? You could try to put the return in the function( data ), perhaps it helps? It probably won't help, but it's better then pulling your hair out ;-)

Comment: Yeah, it alerts just fine... just not posting to the page in question. But I made a new HTML page with just the two divs and javascript above and it seems to work as expected.  So is there something that could interfere with ajax being posted on a particular page?